# How can I output this with a simple PHP for loop?

Tags: php

How can I output these with a simple 'for' loop?

```
####*
###**
##***
#****
*****

*****
#****
##***
###**
####*
```

hashtag = spaces

I've tried to changing the * and the 'br' within this one:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
  for($b = 0; $b <= $i; $b++) {
    echo '*';
  }
  echo "</br>";
}
```

But than it will just output them under each other >.>

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: I smell homework.

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
    for($k=0;$k<5-$i;$k++){
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<br>";
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    for($k=0;$k<5-$i;$k++){
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

My Solution. Next time you should do your homework by yourself ;-)

Comment: You've made my day :)